# Data binding package does not exist

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-room

I'm working on an app using databinding and room. The databinding works fine when I first created it, everything went well. But when I modify or add a new room module totally independent of the earlier module which worked, it shows "databinding package does not exist" for the one which worked earlier.

I'm not sure how it is linked.

Comment: I think  it is a duplicate question, you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934249/android-databinding-package-does-not-exist/41195335)

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was due to logical errors in the RoomDatabase file but it would show me errors like ""databinding package does not exist" which didn't seem relevant to the actual problem.